# Move jenkins to another disk - who should be the owner?

Tags: jenkins, symlink, http-status-code-503, chown

I am moving my Jenkins installation to new disk mounted at `/data` and my structure is following:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 jenkins jenkins 13 Nov  5 14:36 /usr/share/jenkins -> /data/jenkins
lrwxrwxrwx 1 jenkins jenkins 20 Nov  5 15:32 /var/cache/jenkins -> /data/jenkins/cache/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 jenkins jenkins 19 Nov  5 14:42 /var/lib/jenkins -> /data/jenkins/home/
```

I moved everything while Jenkins service was stopped. Now when I start Jenkins service my page says:

```
Service Unavailable

The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.

Apache/2.4.9 (Ubuntu) Server at XXX Port 80
```

I think, that problem will be with owning of Jenkins files or maybe symlinks. All files I moved has chown set to jenkins:jenkins.

Any ideas?

Comment: We're you able to find any info in apache server logs ?

Comment: @RaghavVaidhyanathan I am sorry, I don't really understand it but today it's working.